# Difference in noise performance between UK system and US installation

Tags: noise, mains, measurement

We have a piece of high-gain measurement equipment that we tested extensively in the UK and the found to perform adequately. This is a mains powered device, with the electronics powered through a commercial switched-mode power supply, which kicks out spikes at 67kHz, with harmonics well in band in the range 1-10 MHz.

In the UK, the 67kHz spikes are not visible on the output measurements at all. This is true on two distinct (though ostensibly identical) units.

However, when the system is used in the US (at one location), the 67kHz spikes are distinctly present on the output data.

I played around quite a bit with reducing the noise on the line and found a couple of tricks that should do it, including moving a voltage sense wire required by the PSU and adding a line filter, as well as making sure the power supply was well isolated from the chassis earth except through a single earthing cable. I can get the (I think) common mode noise down to about 100mV, which I'm hoping is going to fix the problem.

However, I still have a nagging doubt about the root cause of the issue. Are there differences between the US and UK supplies that might cause such problems?

I've tested the system in the UK at 110V (though still 50Hz) and the noise spikes were slightly bigger, but I still didn't see them on the data.

I'm somewhat suspicious that the earth at the US site is causing a problem. Perhaps it has high inductance or something and so looks like high impedance at the frequencies of interest, so high frequency noise coupled into the data line screening is not being adequately sunk. How can I test this? (or mitigate it if it is an issue?)

FWIW, a system in continental Europe seems to be working just fine.

The received signals are single ended outputs passed over coax from ultrasound transducers, referenced to system zero volts. The signal then goes through a high gain amplifier and is digitised.

The system zero volts is coupled at various distributed locations through capacitors to chassis earth and the chassis (largely big pieces of aluminum) earth is bonded to the PCB's at various points.

The aim was to have the system earth as continuous as possible. The only place this isn't true now is that PSU's chassis is isolated from the system earth and the only connection is through an earthing cable to one of the common chassis earthing points, which also is where the mains earth is connected.

Comment: I think it's a good question but could have all sorts of reasons, many of which are circuit details.. What is "output" ? Is it chassis referenced ? I.e. how is your circuit ground attached to the chassis ? And also a lot of detail about your power distribution network would be necessary. At that point I think that the issue exceeds the scope of a SE question. But maybe you want to give it a try and add this to the question so there would be the chance of a sensible answer. As Earth is regarded "protective" in all the world, I doubt mains Earth impedance is the issue.

Comment: Active noise suppression tuned to 50Hz won't work as well at 60Hz. Is the commercial power supply switching synchronously to reduce noise or reactive power?

Comment: @david I don't know - that's a good question and something bear in mind... It's a meanwell supply, so I'd be surprised if it's not largely internationally agnostic, but one never knows.